# Task is block the UI instead of returing a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform : when I click a button, it calls a method that calls a web service but after the web call executes, the method is not returning the string and the UI is constantly loading.

The webform code looks like this:

```
Task<string> result = TheWebService.SendWebRequest();
Output.Text = result.Result; //an aspx Literal control
```

The web service code looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> SendWebRequest()
{       
   response = await client.PostAsync(request);

   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
     return "1";
   }
   else
   {
     return "2";
    }
}
```

The `Output.Text = result.Result;` never executes and instead the page is loading endlessly. What do I need to change in my code so that the result is display in the page?

Comment: Have you tried `Output.Text = await TheWebService.SendWebRequest();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead of `Result`, use [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Web Forms is a very dated technology at this point, so using `async` isn't incredibly straightforward. You'll need to [set `Page.Async` to `true` and then register your asynchronous task using `PageAsyncTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: Ok, I think this is good; in the meantime, I changed things around but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code, to prevent deadlock:

```cs
Output.Text = TheWebService.SendWebRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

```
response = await client.PostAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But you should be aware, this is just workaround. The code runs synchronously.